# How i can get the most recent file inside "List files in folder" one drive

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, onedrive-for-business

I have this flow, where i am getting all the root folders inside a user onedrive:-

[image]

then i am using "List files in folder" >> to get all the files inside each root folder. but i do not need all files i only need the latest file inside each of the root folders? any advice?

Thanks